# How do i add a polgon in the gmap3.js code (wordpress)

Tags: polygon, jquery-gmap3

How do I set the coordinates por a polygon in this code..?
This a pieace of the Gmap3.js code on my website. And I want to add some polygons into it..

`enter code here`function poly(args, poly, path){
      var objs = [], multiple = "values" in args.todo;
      if (!multiple){
        args.todo.values = [{options:args.opts}];
      }
      if (!args.todo.values.length){
        manageEnd(args, false);
        return;
      }
      newMap();
      $.each(args.todo.values, function(_, value){
        var id, i, j, obj, todo = tuple(args, value);
        if (todo.options[path]){
          if (todo.options[path][0][0] && $.isArray(todo.options[path][0][0])){
            for(i=0; ipoly;
        objs.push(obj);
        id = store.add({todo:todo}, poly.toLowerCase(), obj);
        attachEvents($this, {todo:todo}, obj, id);
      });
      manageEnd(args, multiple ? objs : objs[0]);
    }

```
this.polyline = function(args){
  poly(args, "Polyline", "path");
};

this.polygon = function(args){
  poly(args, "Polygon", "paths");
};
```